# Hole in the proof of the uniqueness of the neutral element?

Tags: logic

I assume you know the standard proof that finishes: $ e_1 = e_2$. But so far it just proves that two fixed neutral elements are equal, what if we introduce $e_3$ and more? So the standard proof does not seem be bulletproof. More precisely it must finish with something like: $\forall e_{i,j \in \mathbb N}: e_i = e_j$. Only now thru the logical law of transitivity it makes sure that any neutral elements are equal to each other, therefore just one unique neutral element exists. Is my observation correct?

Comment: The standard proof you refer to shows any two neutral elements are the same. It's then essentially obvious that there is at most one such element. Your observation is correct, but not worth making a fuss over in all but the most formal of proof systems. Not needed in everyday  mathematics.

Comment: @EthanBolker Actually, even in a super-formal context the OP's point will usually not be needed - this is because "the neutral element is unique" is itself expressed as "Any two neutral elements are equal." So there really is no issue at any level.

Comment: You should quote the proof you're referring to. There isn't one "standard proof". Perhaps the proof you're talking about has some strange wording that could be improved. The statement you want to prove is: $\forall a, b: \text{is_neutral_element}(a) \land \text{is_neutral_element}(b) \implies a = b$

Comment: @Noah But what if I introduce e2 and e3 as two different neutral elements that are assumed to differ from e1? Then you need the proof (e1 = e2) plus  the law of transitivity, right?

Answer (score 1):

You mention the word "unique" in the tile of the post so I'll remind what exactly that means. Suppose we have a property $P(x)$, and an object $a$.
We say that an object $a$ is unique to property $P(x)$ if $P(a)$ holds, and for any other *arbitrary* object $b$, if $P(b)$ holds, then $a = b$.
This is **by definition** of uniqueness.

If you have disagreement about this as a definition, remember about how universal quantification works. Sure, we are taking the object $a$ and "comparing" it with only one other arbitrary candidate object $b$, but since $b$ is arbitrary, it concludes something for *all other objects*.

Now, given a property $P(x)$, we can say there exists a unique $x$ such that $P(x)$ if we can demonstrate that there exists an object $a$ such that $P(a)$ holds, and that for any other $b$, if $P(b)$ holds, then $a = b$.

Let's look at the theorem and proof technique you mentioned.
Here $P(x)$ is the statement "$x$ is the identity element of the group $G$."
And the theorem we are working towards is that there exists unique $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds. That is, there is a unique element of $G$ that is the identity of $G$.

For the proof, we already have the existence of such an element, call it $e$, by the group axioms. In other settings, it could be the case that it takes alot of work to actually find the candidate "unique object," but here, we get it for free.
To show that this group element, $e$, is unique, we must take another arbitrary group element, call it $f$, suppose it satisfies the identity property, and hopefully conclude that $e = f$.

This is exactly what the proof you mention concludes, maybe just with different notation.
Also you mention about showing it "$\forall_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}} e_{i} = e_j$", but this is both unnecessary (because universal quantification and the arbitrary nature of the other object already accounts for infinitely many objects), and insufficient (since your quantification I believe assumes only countably any objects, where as these sets can have arbitrarily large size).
Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Sprinkle But your proof just shows that e = f, not that e = f = g for instance when I assume two different neutral elements apart from e. To prove that you need to apply the law of transitivity, right?

Comment: It seems you still have a few misconceptions about how it works. First of all, there is no "law of transitivity" when it comes to this, but I'll try and explain along what you may be getting at. As before, suppose I first did the proof I did above, and show that if $f$ is ANY arbitrary other element (think if it as a place holder) of $G$ with the identity, then $e = f$. Now suppose I take, say other elements $g$ and $k$ in $G$ that also satisfy the identity property. Then I can, with setting $f = g$ and $f = k$ (since $f$ is a universally quantified placeholder), say $g = f = e$, $k = f = e$.

Comment: If this is confusing still, then your misunderstanding stems not from this individual proof, but from the concept of uniqueness and why it is defined as I mentioned in my original post. I would advise rereading sections from books like "How to Prove It" or "Book of Proof" (freely available) and reading the sections on uniqueness proofs. If that isn't enough, then perhaps searching on here and other sites for discussion on uniqueness, and if that doesn't suffice, perhaps a post.

Comment: I also want to mention, in your comment, you say "assume two different neutral elements", your not suppose to assume two "different" neutral elements, rather just two neutral elements. If I say, let $m$ and $n$ be natural numbers, there is the possibility that they are different, and that they are the same. If I specify some property about these two natural numbers, it could very well mean that they are equal. For example, let $m$ and $n$ be two positive divisors of $7$ that are not equal to $1$. It can then be deduced that $m = 7 = n$, even though I called them different names.

Answer (score -1):

The operation in question, may have to be commutative. Then you would have:

[image]
[image]
[image]